# Xamarin iOS custom renderer frame back to default when app back from background to foreground

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In Xamarin project in iOS I am creating customer renderer for light shadows. When someone press home button, apps goes to backgroud, but when he wants to bring app back to foreground, view renders frame as normal frame (without customer renderer features).

In App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    // logic for change visibility of frame
    FrameVisible = false;
    FrameVisible = true;
}
```

It is ugly solution and for short moment (about 300ms) when view is small until it is getting larger until full screen frame renderer shadow is strong (bad) and then it changes to light (adjust custom renderer).

Is there any nice  solution to adjust custom renderer frame when app is minimized (before it back to full screen) or keep customer renderer all the time on?

Comment: *"view renders frame as normal frame (without customer renderer features)."* If you put breakpoints in your custom renderer, are any of those breakpoints hit when app is brought back to foreground? Or add Debug.WriteLine calls at start of each custom method, to see which are called when. Perhaps renderer gets used, but some method isn't called the second time. If so, perhaps you can devise a solution, once you know which methods are called, and which are not.

Comment: `I am creating customer renderer for light shadows.` Could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?